# multiple values in 1 column when you join 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

table 1 - employee

```
id  empname
--------------
1   andy
2   brady
```

table 2 - employee phone numbers

```
id number empid
----------------
1  1111   1
2  2222   2
3  3333   1
4  4444   1
```

Need a sql query to display the following

```
id empname numbers
------------------
1  andy    1111,3333,4444
2  brady   2222
```

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using? [tag:mysql], [tag:sql-server] and [tag:oracle] are different databases.

Comment: I removed them all. Put one of them back, the one for the dbms actually used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using MySQL, you can use GROUP_CONCAT funcion, that basically concatenate every value composing the group. You could try this:

```
SELECT EMP.ID,
       EMP.EMPNAME,
       GROUP_CONCAT(EPH.NUMBER) AS NUMBERS
  FROM EMPLOYEE EMP
  JOIN EMPLOYEE_PHONE EPH
    ON EMP.ID = EPH.EMPID
 GROUP BY EMP.ID
```

Also, if you want to separate your values with something different of a "," you can add the syntax SEPARATOR " " after the column inside group concat, if you want to separate with spaces in this particular example

Answer (score 1):

if you use SQL SERVER I think this will do it for you, if not maybe a close guess without data. But! I used STUFF and selected the `Number` and split them by `,` and ordered it

```
SELECT 
   t1.ID,t2v1.empname,
   STUFF((SELECT ',' + t2v2.number
          FROM Table2 t2v2
          WHERE t2v2.ID = t2v1.ID
          ORDER BY number
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') [numbers]
FROM Table1 t1 
inner join table2 t2v1 on t1.id = t2v1.id
GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.Name
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: Or just use [`STRING_AGG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) if you're on SQL Server 2017 or later...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 SELECT e.id, e.name, CONCATENATE(ep.number, ',') as phonelist 
 FROM Employees e INNER JOIN EmployeePhone ep ON e.id = ep.empid
```

Reference Doc: http://www.peteonsoftware.com/index.php/2009/12/11/creating-a-comma-separated-list-from-a-sql-grouping/

Comment: "_However, nothing like that was to be found._"